# How to stop a div element containing a Kendo UI dataviz chart from overlapping other elements when zoomed in and on tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am using the default example of the Kendo UI dataviz bar chart. When I zoom into the page, the graph starts to overlap over other elements on the page. Is there a way to make sure that everything in the div containing the graph does not overlap onto other divs. This is a huge problem as when viewed on a tablet, it is overlapping other elements.

Answer (score 0):

How are you "zooming" in?

The KendoChart gets a fixed width when it is created - it's just an SVG. I'm not aware of a means to animate resizing it - you could change the height and width manually, or possibly just redraw the chart, but I imagine that would be fairly intensive and wouldn't animate well.